# knockout js binding doesn't bind the grid titles correctly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using knockout.js with Kendo-UI.
I have this grid model:

```
var GridModel = function (options) {
        function GridItem(item) {
            return { Id: item.Id() || '', Description: item.Description() };
        }

        $.extend(this, {
            data: ko.observableArray(),
            gridOptions: {
                pageable: true,
                pageSize: 5,
                sortable: true,
                scrollable: false,
                selectable: true,
                columns: [
                        { field: 'Id', title: 'title1', width: '80px', groupable: false },
                        { field: 'Description', title: 'title2', width: '200px', groupable: false }
                ]
            }
        });

        this.addItem = function (item) {
            this.data.push(new GridItem(item));
        }
    };
```

This is my markup:

```
<div id="GridDiv" data-bind="kendoGrid: data, gridOptions: gridOptions"></div>
```

This is how I apply the binding:

```
ko.applyBindings(new GridModel(), $('#GridDiv').get(0));
```

For some reason the titles of the columns are not binded and instead of title1 and title2, I get Id and Description.
Moreover, if I replace `this.data.push(new GridItem(item));` with `this.data.push(item);` then instead of 2 columns, I get 10 columns (because item contains 10 members).

Why doesn't the binding work correctly?

Update:
I added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mTqdE/14/ but somehow it doesn't work.. any idea?

Comment: Could you post your code in a fiddle?

Comment: @Artem Vyshniakov: I added a jsfiddle but I can't run it..

Comment: Does removing the title: 'title1' and title: 'title2' option from your columns definition help?

Comment: @Mark Robinson: No, it doesn't help. But I need those titles also. Removing it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have [an example](http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html) how to correctly pass additional options with Knockout bindings:

[Here's working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mTqdE/16/):

```
<div id="GridDiv" data-bind="kendoGrid: gridOptions"></div>
<button data-bind="click: addRandomItem">add</button>
```

And pass `data` as a grid option.

Comment: You know, I have other code of my colege and it also works, and I did exactly like him (the data is outside the gridOptions). But for me it didn't work. In the other hand, your code did work. How come?? 

Thanks!